# Eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of the Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, brownian-motion, upper-lower-bounds, covariance

Let $t_1< \dots < t_p$ be distinct points within $(0,1)$ and consider the $p \times p$ matrix $\mathbf{C}$ with entries $$c_{ij} = \min(t_i,t_j)$$ Please note that this is a well-known matrix as it is the covariance matrix of the Wiener process on $(0,1)$. I have been wondering if there exist closed form expressions for its eigenvalues. I am particularly interested in the behavior of the largest and smallest eigenvalues of this matrix as a function of $p$. References are also welcome, as this question is likely to have been asked and answered before. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://doi.org/10.1515/spma-2016-0010)

Comment: [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209249) might also be useful

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the reference. If I understand it well, it follows from Theorem 5.1 that the smallest eigenvalue equals the minimum of $|t_i-t_{i-1}|$?

Comment: Is that factorization an eigendecomposition?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo No, indeed. There are strong indications that the smallest eigenvalue is proportional to $\min|t_i-t_{i-1}|$ but there is no proof as far as I can see.

Comment: If those papers are useless, their references may be less so

Comment: Even the simplest matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$$ has the rather "complicated" eigenvalues $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}\,.$